# Optimal 1d kernel density bandwidth in Python

Tags: python, bandwidth, kernel-density

Is there any direct function that computes the optimal bandwidth for a univariate density estimation in Python? In scikit-learn, the KernelDensity function has nothing predefined.

I want to avoid grid searching and would like to have something that you enter with a vector and it comes out a value, it could be any of the classic rules (rule-of-thumbs, plug-in, Silverman, Sheater and Jones, etc.) like the functions bw.nrd0 and bw.nrd of R.

Best.

Comment: you have to option to do cross validation in statsmodel: http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density.KDEMultivariateConditional.html

Comment: Thanks! I actually solved the problem using the 'stats' module:

kde1 = stats.gaussian_kde(X1, bw_method = 'silverman')